# Applying filters on a Tableau -Dashboard without iterating the sheets

Tags: javascript, jquery, tableau-api

Is there any way where we can directly apply filters on the tableau dashboard without iterating the sheets of the dashboard

For now I am doing this way:

```
worksheet = viz.getWorkbook().getActiveSheet().getWorksheets();

for (var i = 0; i< worksheet .length; i++) {
   worksheet[i].applyFilterAsync(name, value, 'ADD')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a filter apply to all worksheets that use the same data source. On a worksheet, right-click the field on the Filters shelf and select **Apply to Worksheets > All Using This Data Source**.

See the online help at https://onlinehelp.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/filtering_global.html.